# How to get the process status only with "R" in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

--Need to get the status of the background running script.

Initially, I ran the script and terminated it turned to stat "T"
[image]

further, running the same script but while grep getting the script with stat "T"and "R"
[image]

Here, how to get the process with only "R". here is the command used

`ps aux | grep test.sh | grep -v grep`

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Gilles i don't have copy paste access to that environment. so i snipped it.

Comment: You can take screenshot but not copy/paste ? Which particular environment do you use to not be able to copy paste ?

Comment: Anyway thank you much @Gilles Quenot. it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
ps aux | awk '$7 == "R+"'
```

Comment: script name will be dynamic.so i can't test[.]sh is there anyway and it will be good if i have 'bash' instead of 'awk'

Comment: Check my edit. bash is just like an orchestrer with third party tools

Comment: IMO You should to explain a bit more about `awk` utility. "_Use this_" is not very informative, sorry (I know about awk language, but I cares about future readers).

Comment: Currently the STAT column is in position 8, so the command now is: 

ps aux | awk '$8 == "R+"'